# Why does setting an iterator to a variable in Python behave differently than using it directly in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, data-structures, iterator, list-comprehension

I was not expecting the first output, though it kind of makes sense. A raw iterator only cycles through once. The thing I don't understand is why it behaves differently if the `reversed()` function is used in the comprehension statement.

```
>>> old_list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> rev_old = reversed(old_list)
>>> [i + a for i in old_list for a in rev_old]
['ho', 'hl', 'hl', 'he', 'hh']
>>> [i + a for i in old_list for a in reversed(old_list)]
['ho', 'hl', 'hl', 'he', 'hh', 'eo', 'el', 'el', 'ee', 'eh', 'lo', 'll', 'll', 'le', 'lh', 'lo', 'll', 'll', 'le', 'lh', 'oo', 'ol', 'ol', 'oe', 'oh']
```

Comment: because you are re-evaluating `reversed(old_list)` in the second case for every value of `old_list`.

Comment: Right, ok that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method evaluates `reversed(old_list)` only once.  Its equivalent code would be this:

```
rev_old = reversed(old_list)
lst = []
for i in old_list:
    for a in rev_old:
        lst.append(i + a)
```

The second one however re-evaluates `reversed(old_list)` multiple times.  Its equivalent code would be this:

```
lst = []
for i in old_list:
    for a in reversed(old_list):
        lst.append(i + a)
```

In the above code, the `reversed(old_list)` part of `for a in reversed(old_list):` is evaluated with each iteration of `for i in old_list:`.

---

Regarding your comment, what you have is a [nested list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions). The equivalent code of this:

```
[[str(x)+'+'+str(y) for x in [10,30,50]] for y in [20,40,60]]
```

would be this:

```
outer = []
for y in [20,40,60]:
    inner = []
    for x in [10,30,50]:
        inner.append(str(x)+'+'+str(y))
    outer.append(inner)
```

Comment: What doesn't really make a ton of sense is that the actual order of operations is the reverse of this. Try `[str(x)+'+'+str(y) for x in [10,30,50] for y in [20,40,60]]`

Comment: I was confusing `[str(x)+'+'+str(y) for x in [10,30,50] for y in [20,40,60]]` with `[[str(x)+'+'+str(y) for x in [10,30,50]] for y in [20,40,60]]`

Comment: @JoshRusso - Yea, I thought so.  I'll include the code's breakdown in my answer though just for a refresher. :)